# How to send email via SMTP using MailSo library (PHP)

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have a hard time to send multipart MIME message via SMTP using PHP library called [MailSo](https://github.com/detochko/MailSo). Provided two examples are limited. No word on how to create headers, message body, multipart MIME message itself and then send it.

Current webmail (Rainloop) is running on MailSo and I want to avoid using 3rd party library on top of MailSo. Going forward all email actions are stored in the Rainloop Actions.php file.

Based on that to create multipart MIME message I should to create `$oMessage` object (`\MailSo\Mime\Message`) and I'm able partially do that like to add subject, message ID, custom headers, message body text but going further I'm not able to set MIME boundaries (to store original message body as a boundary as well additional content type as text/plain) not talking about sending `$oMessage` object via SMTP.

Here is my test code so far:

```
include 'lib/MailSo/MailSo.php';

echo '<pre>';
$oLogger = \MailSo\Log\Logger::SingletonInstance()
    ->Add(\MailSo\Log\Drivers\Inline::NewInstance("\r\n", true))
;

$sToEmails = 'Me As Tester <tester@test.com>';
$oToEmails = \MailSo\Mime\EmailCollection::NewInstance($sToEmails);

$sFromEmails = 'Baba Ganush <no-replay@test.com>';
$oFromEmails = \MailSo\Mime\Email::NewInstance($sFromEmails);

$oMessage = \MailSo\Mime\Message::NewInstance();
$oMessage->RegenerateMessageId();

$oMessage->SetXMailer('RainLoop/1.0.0');

$oMessage->SetCustomHeader('test-header','test-header-value');

$oMessage->setSubject("Test message");
$oMessage->AddText('Generated message body goes here...');

$oMessage->SetFrom($oFromEmails);
$oMessage->SetTo($oToEmails);

$oLogger->WriteDump($oMessage);
```

Comment: Why not use something much more known like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Comment: @PatrickQ I have PHPMailer or Swift Mailer as a final choice but current webmail (Rainloop) is running on MailSo

Comment: we are not the support for every third party app

Comment: How are you sending regular messages using this library? Can you post the code you have that _is_ working and the code that you've tried that _isn't_?

Comment: @PatrickQ I have updated OP. I may update more when I will proceed with a discovery on Rainloop part how MailSo works.

Comment: @PatrickQ OP updated with more info and my test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have figured out how to send an email message created using MailSo library (w/o any attachments for now)

Example code below

```
        if($oMessage){
            $rMessageStream = \MailSo\Base\ResourceRegistry::CreateMemoryResource();
            $iMessageStreamSize = \MailSo\Base\Utils::MultipleStreamWriter($oMessage->ToStream(true), array($rMessageStream), 8192, true, true, true);
        }

        $aToCollection = $oMessage->GetTo();
        if ($aToCollection && $oFrom)
        {
            $sRawBody = @stream_get_contents($rMessageStream);

            if (!empty($sRawBody))
            {
                $sMailTo = trim($aToCollection->ToString(true));
                $sMailSubject = trim($oMessage->GetSubject());
                $sMailSubject = 0 === strlen($sMailSubject) ? '' : \MailSo\Base\Utils::EncodeUnencodedValue(\MailSo\Base\Enumerations\Encoding::BASE64_SHORT, $sMailSubject);
                $sMailHeaders = $sMailBody = '';
                list($sMailHeaders, $sMailBody) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $sRawBody, 2);
                unset($sRawBody);
                $sMailHeaders = \MailSo\Base\Utils::RemoveHeaderFromHeaders($sMailHeaders, array(\MailSo\Mime\Enumerations\Header::TO_,\MailSo\Mime\Enumerations\Header::SUBJECT));
                mail($sMailTo, $sMailSubject, $sMailBody, $sMailHeaders);
            }
        }
```